# Flutter DropdownButton - Add title for separating items

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, dropdownbutton

Im trying to implement a `DropdownButton` that can separate specific items from each other with a title (see desired output on image below, the titles are in green)

[image: The green title separates the items of the dropdown]

Like in the example I would like to add these green titles to my existing `DropdownButton`, but did not find anything that showed me how to add something else than items to a `DropdownButton`

I also tried to switch from `DropdownButton` to a `ListView` with `ExpansionTile` but I would like to keep the behaviour of the `DropdownButton`...

Is it possible to add these titles to the `DropdownButton` `items`? Or shourd I try to achive it by a other way? Im stuck at the moment and dont know how to proceed

Comment: I believe there is no Widget that does exactly what you are looking for. The currently available Flutter Widgets were created for Mobile devices and this kind of title inside a DropDown is something that takes a lot of space and tends to have difficult usability. I haven't found any packages available to reproduce this either. You will most likely have to build it yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this code in dartpad:

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      
      home: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return HomeScreen();
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomeScreenState createState() => HomeScreenState();
}

class HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  String dropdownValue;
  List<Product> products = [
    Product(name: 'sep1', type: 'sep'),
    Product(name: 'milk', type: 'data'),
    Product(name: 'oil', type: 'data'),
    Product(name: 'sep2', type: 'sep'),
    Product(name: 'suger', type: 'data'),
    Product(name: 'salt', type: 'data'),
    Product(name: 'sep3', type: 'sep'),
    Product(name: 'potatoe', type: 'data'),
    Product(name: 'tomatoe', type: 'data'),
    Product(name: 'apple', type: 'data'),
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('text')),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text('test'),
          Expanded(
            child: DropdownButton<String>(
              value: dropdownValue,
              items: products.map((value) {
                return DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: value.name,
                  child: value.type == 'data'
                      ? Text(value.name)
                      : Divider(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          thickness: 3,
                        ),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (newValue) {
                
                setState(() {
                  
                    dropdownValue = newValue;
                  
                });
                print('$newValue $dropdownValue');
                
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Product {
  String name;
  String type;

  Product({this.name, this.type});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort! Nice workaround but a integrated seperator for dropdown items would be very nice to have! But as it is one year since I asked, I suggest this would be the best way to implement dropdown seperators... I'll mark as answer

Comment: i hope it help you

Comment: Flutter 2.5 adds `enabled` parameter to `DropdownMenuItem`. Use it to disable your separators so they are not tappable.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Ali Tenni's answer you can also subclass `DropdownMenuItem` like this:

```dart
class DropdownMenuItemSeparator<T> extends DropdownMenuItem<T> {
  DropdownMenuItemSeparator() : super(
    enabled: false,     // As of Flutter 2.5.
    child: Container(), // Trick the assertion.
  ); 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Divider(thickness: 3);
  }
}
```

This will make the separator more narrow because otherwise the default `build()` adds some min height.

**UPD 2021-09-14** *Below is no longer relevant as the feature is implemented in Flutter 2.5. The code above updated accordingly.*

This solves one of the two problems. Unfortunately, the second and the larger problem is that the separator is still tappable, and the tap closes the dropdown. To address this, I submitted a feature request to Flutter:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/75487

Comment: Thanks for your answer & for filling the feature request to the Flutter team!
It hope they thought about this and add a solution for making sub menus in dropdowns, which arent selectable hehe ^^

Comment: how to use it and how about `DropdownMenuItem` variables like onTap, child etc?

Comment: i think for separator menu item to be more narrow, DropdownButton must have                 itemHeight: null,

Answer (score 0):

This is my code from a closed question: [How to create a dropdown menu with sections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71921018/how-to-create-a-dropdown-menu-with-sections)

The y position of the accepted anwser change. I don't understand why it's an accepted anwser.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomDropDownMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const CustomDropDownMenu({Key? key, required this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomDropDownMenu createState() => _CustomDropDownMenu();
}

class _CustomDropDownMenu extends State<CustomDropDownMenu>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  OverlayEntry? overlayEntry;

  late AnimationController _animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MouseRegion(
      onExit: (onExit) {
        setOnExitMenu(context, onExit.delta.dy);
      },
      child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            insertOverlay(context);
            _animationController.forward();
          },
          child: widget.child),
    );
  }

  void setOnExitMenu(BuildContext context, double delta) {
    if (delta >= 0) {
      return;
    }
    closeDropDown();
  }

  void insertOverlay(BuildContext context) {
    closeDropDown();
    final rect = findParamsData(context);
    overlayEntry = _createOverlay(rect: rect);
    Overlay.of(context)!.insert(overlayEntry!);
  }

  OverlayEntry _createOverlay({required Rect rect}) {
    return OverlayEntry(builder: (context) {
      return Material(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
          children: [
            Positioned(
              child: IgnorePointer(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.black45,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned.fromRect(
                rect: Rect.fromLTWH(
                    rect.left, rect.top, rect.width * 3, rect.height * 10),
                child: SlideTransition(
                    position: Tween(
                            begin: const Offset(0, 0.15),
                            end: const Offset(0, 0))
                        .animate(_animationController),
                    child: MouseRegion(
                      onExit: (onExit) {
                        setOnExitMenu(context, -1);
                      },
                      child: const ContentDropDown(),
                    )
                )),
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
  }

  Rect findParamsData(BuildContext context) {
    final RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject()! as RenderBox;

    final size = renderBox.size;
    final offset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);

    return Rect.fromLTWH(
        offset.dx, offset.dy + size.height, size.width, size.height);
  }

  void closeDropDown() {
    if (overlayEntry != null) {
      overlayEntry!.remove();
      overlayEntry = null;
    }
  }
}

class ContentDropDown extends StatelessWidget {
  const ContentDropDown({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          border: Border.all(
              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
              width: 0.5)),
      child: ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: [
          TextFormField(),
          ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: 10,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  leading: Image.network(
                      "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/nap/thumb/f/f3/Logo_UEFA_Champions_League.png/250px-Logo_UEFA_Champions_League.png"),
                  title: const Text("Champions League"),
                );
              }),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```